# How can I define a constraint in between two tables but only if the foreign key is not null?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have two tables. Table1 has a foreign key that represents a valid primary key in another table (Table2). Now the problem is that this foreign key can sometimes can be null (it is suppose to be like that). How can I check the constraint only when the foreign key is not null?

PD> I'm currently programming in C# and I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: create a stored procedure for inserting and updating Table1 that raises an error when the foreign key is null.

Comment: Um, foreign keys are generally allowed to be null in my experience.  Are you finding that this is not the case?  What unexpected error message or behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I get an error saying that the insertion can not be applied because of the constraint.

Comment: Try posting the exact text of the message.  Perhaps there's a "not null" constraint in addition to the foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, FK constraints work exactly as you described - they only verify NOT NULL values against the parent table. Just use a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional "CHECK" constraint to the table that would enable you to pass the value into a function to check the value.  Just a thought...

Take a look here for an example [link](http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-function-based-check.html)